# How to avoid blocking call within Spring Webflux MessageSource load bundle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, blockhound

I have a Spring Boot application (Spring Boot version '2.5.2') using Spring Webflux and the following `RestControllerAdvice`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class CommentControllerAdvice {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    @Data
    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Builder
    public static class ErrorResponse {

        Date timestamp;
        String path;
        int status;
        String error;
        String message;
        String requestId;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleWebExchangeBindException(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                                                        Locale locale,
                                                                        WebExchangeBindException e) {
        var validationError = ErrorCode.VALIDATION_ERROR;
        var httpStatus = validationError.getHttpStatus();
        var apiMessage = messageSource.getMessage(validationError.name(), null, locale);
        log.error(String.format("%s - %s", request.getId(), apiMessage), e);

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(httpStatus)
                .body(buildErrorResponse(request, httpStatus, apiMessage));
    }
    
    private ErrorResponse buildErrorResponse(ServerHttpRequest request, HttpStatus httpStatus, String apiMessage) {
        return ErrorResponse.builder()
                .timestamp(new Date())
                .path(request.getPath().value())
                .status(httpStatus.value())
                .error(httpStatus.getReasonPhrase())
                .message(apiMessage)
                .requestId(request.getId())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Whenever the `handleWebExchangeBindException` is triggered during tests, Blockhound detects a blocking call, making them fail.

Am I doing something wrong? I thought MessageSource was safe to use in Spring Webflux, so why is it using a blocking API?

I also want to add that with Spring Boot version '2.4.3' Blockhound does not detect any blocking calls and all my tests pass.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$JwtMutator$$Lambda$2024/0x0000000100c2cc40 [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$MutatorFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers$SetupMutatorFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? HTTP POST "/api/v1/comments" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:279) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:229) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:497) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:416) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:378) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.<init>(PropertyResourceBundle.java:200) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.loadBundle(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:281) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource$MessageSourceControl.newBundle(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:430) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1994) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1776) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1728) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1728) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1662) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1509) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.doGetBundle(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.getResourceBundle(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:211) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(ResourceBundleMessageSource.java:154) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:212) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at com.redditclone.commentservice.comment.CommentControllerAdvice.handleCommentServiceException(CommentControllerAdvice.java:46) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:325) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onSubscribe(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:115) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2062) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onError(MonoSingle.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2399) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollect.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:284) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:325) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onSubscribe(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:115) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onComplete(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onSubscribe(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:115) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener$DelegateTestExecutionListener$SecuritySubContext.onNext(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.java:120) ~[spring-security-test-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
```

Comment: i am no pro when it comes to this, but what i could read from the source code, is that initial loading of the resources is done by reading the resource from the file system which is blocking, and then cached, while subsequent read are done from the cache. So you could try by preloading during startup, then rest of reads should be done from the cache.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. I guess it might make sense to configure Blockhound in order to ignore that particular blocking call, since it only happens once in the lifetime of the application. I just find it weird that in Spring Boot 2.4.3 the blocking call is not detected, but in 2.5.2 it is.